# How can I start all AWS EC2 instances in Ansible

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible

I have found a script for starting/stopping a dynamically created ec2 instance, but how do I start any instances in my inventory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you are talking about scripting, not SDK. So there are two tools to do the job.

## 1  AWS CLI tools

1. download [aws cli tool](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) and set the API Key in $HOME/.aws/credentials
2. list all instances on region us-east-1

Confirm which instances you are targeting.

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].InstanceId' --region us-east-1 --output text
```

## 2 Amazon EC2 Command Line Interface Tools

1. [download and setup instruction](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/set-up-ec2-cli-linux.html#tools-introduction)
2. list all instances on region us-east-1

You should get same output as WAY #1.

```
ec2-describe-instances --region us-west-2 |awk '/INSTANCE/{print $2}'
```

With the instance ID list, you can use your command to start them one by one.

for example, the instance name are saved in file `instance.list`

```
while read instance
do
  echo "Starting instance $instance ..."
  ec2-start-instances "$linstance"
done  < instance.list
```

Answer (score 0):

BMW, give you an excellent startup, but you can even summarise the thing like this: 
1) First get the id of all the instances and save them into a file

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].InstanceId' --region us-east-1 --output text >> id.txt
```

2) Then simply run this command to start all the instances

```
for id in $(awk '{print $1}' id.txt); do echo "starting the following instance $id"; aws ec2 start-instances --instance-ids --region us-east-1 $id; done
```

Please change the region, I am considering that you have installed and setup the AWS CLI tools properly. Thanks